# Inheritance class with child classes and casting

Tags: c#, inheritance

I have base class A and child classes. I am searching a way to build some kind of casting through tree structure of classes.

```
class A
{
   prop b;
   prop c;
   prop d;
   prop E[] e;
   prop F f;
}

class E
{
   prop g;
   prop h;
   prop J j;
}

class J
{
   prop k;
}

class F
{
   prop l;
}
```

Now I am wondering if I could do some inheritance through interfaces or abstract classes wchich would give me various kind of casts like this:

```
 (Cast1)A -> active props: c,d,E.g,E.J.k
 (Cast2)A -> active props: d,F.l
 (Cast3)A -> active props: b, E.h,E.g
```

etc.

How to achieve this? I do not need to always use every property from classes so this casting would be useful for me.

Result would be:

```
var f1 = a as Cast1;
Console.WriteLine(f1.c);
Console.WriteLine(f1.d);
Console.WriteLine(f1.E[0].g);
Console.WriteLine(f1.E[0].h);// this NOT 
Console.WriteLine(f1.E[0].J.k);
Console.WriteLine(f1.E[1].g);

var f2 = a as Cast2;
Console.WriteLine(f2.d);
Console.WriteLine(f2.F.l);

var f3 = a as Cast3;
Console.WriteLine(f3.b);
Console.WriteLine(f3.E[0].h);
Console.WriteLine(f3.E[1].h);
Console.WriteLine(f3.E[2].h);
Console.WriteLine(f3.E[2].g);
```

Comment: What are you trying to do and what do you mean by active props?

Comment: create interface `Cast1` with `props: c,d,E.g,E.J.k`, interface `Cast2` with `props: d,f.l` and interface `Cast3` with `props: b, E.h,E.g`. Them implement them in you classes respectively

Comment: (Cast1)A. will show in a property list c,d,E. (Cast1)A.E. will show in a property list g, J. (Cast1)A.E.J. will show k.

Answer (score 1):

Not quite sure if I understand your question, but it douns like you want to cast a class based on a specific interface?

```
interface IFoo
{
    void Hello1();
    void Hello2();
}

interface IBar
{
    void World1();
    void World2();
}

class A1 : IFoo, IBar
{
//.....
}

var a = new A1();

var f = a as IFoo; // Get IFoo methods.

Console.WriteLine(f.Hello1());

var b = a as IBar; // Get IBar methods.

Console.WriteLine(b.World2());
```

Forgive me if I have the wrong idea, I'll delete my answer if it's not suitable for you.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what your question, what you want can be achieved by defining several interfaces, and having your main class implement them all.

```
interface ICast1
{
    prop c;
    prop d;
    E e;
}

interface ICast2
{
    prop d;
    F f;
}

class A : ICast1, ICast2
{
    prop c;
    prop d;
    E e;
    F f;
}
```

Now you can cast to `ICast1` or `ICast2` and get only the views you want.

Your example is a bit more complex, though, with `E` being filtered as well. You'll need something more complicated here - have two different `E` interfaces, and have them overlap in your `ICast` interfaces. The you can use [Explicit Interface Implementation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288461%28v=vs.71%29.aspx) to differentiate between them.

```
interface E1
{ 
     prop g;
     prop h;
}
interface E2
{
     J j;
}
class E : E1, E2
{
     prop g; prop h; J j;
}
interface ICast1
{
    E1 e;
}
interface ICast2
{
    E2 e;
}
class A : ICast1, ICast2
{
    E1 ICast1.e {get;set;}
    E2 ICast2.e {get;set;}
}
```